# Execute Final script only on build failure

Tags: shell, bamboo

I want to execute an arbitrary shell script, but I only want it to run on build failure.  Is there some way to either:

- Set up Bamboo to run this script only on build failure
- Or check from within the script whether the build was successful.  Perhaps an environment/build variable?

Thoughts and ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bamboo unfortunately lacks a way to trigger something on failure. You can not launch other plan, other stage and so on - you can only send basic notification.

As some workaround, you can move all the jobs to one stage, and have the script in the Final section. You can pass `${bamboo.buildNumber}` to your script, and based on that number request status data from https://user:password@yourproject.atlassian.net/builds/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECT/BUILD_NUMBER.json?expand=stages.stage.results - then you only have to parse the json and get your build state from `json['stages']['stage'][0]['state']`

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this issue is more rudimentary and consists of 3 custom tasks:

- one at the end of the tasks list which creates a status file, name is arbitrary but consistent, e.g. `build.success`
- one at the beginning of the tasks list that deletes the status file (in case workdir directory cleanup is not enabled)
- one task in the beginning of the final tasks list which checks on the existence of `build.success` file and acts accordingly

My use case for the above is sending notifications to IM system not supported by Bamboo plugins (RocketChat). Current limitations:

- final tasks which run after the first one (that consumes the `build.success` file) and fail are not detected
- no detection of stopped runs: the final task is always executed
- complex logic when there are multiple stages, e.g. I add an extra initial stage for sending notifications at build start and an extra stage at the end for sending a "successful build" notification

It's ridiculous that a CI/CD system would not implement some kind of env var like "bamboo.build.result".

Comment: Checked my implementation again and got reminded that what I describe above is only used for deployments (i.e. deployment environments). My implementation for plan notifications is what @kibitzer describes in his answer.