How can I delete uploads to jfrog by bamboo-jfrog-plugin, in case the build fails?
Let's say I have a plan with 2 stages in Bamboo.
The 1'st stage builds and uploads an artifact to jfrog using the bamboo-jfrog-plugin.
The 2'nd stage do something that fails, meaning the whole build failed.
On that case I wish to revert changes and remove all build artifacts that were pushed to the jfrog artifactory server.
Is there a simple way to "revert" and delete all this plan artifacts?

If you are collecting and publishing build info using JFrog CLI, you can then delete all build artifacts.
The build can be deleted using one of the following JFrog CLI commands:

The build discard command - delete build with its artifacts, for example: jf rt build-discard "my-build" --max-builds=1 --delete-artifacts
Delete artifacts command with --build - only delete the artifacts.
The cURL command combined with the delete builds REST API.


Thank you. I wasn't aware of "collecting and publishing build info". I thought I'll just delete all artifacts with a specific tag.
My question here is actually, how/when do I trigger automatically such a thing? I thought about using a final stage in a Bamboo plan. There, automatically understand if the build failed, and then trigger that jf command to delete. Though I'm not sure how yet...

Maybe the workaround here could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635097/execute-final-script-only-on-build-failure?rq=3

That's the thing I learned as well.
Thank you!
